# How to slide images in from the side using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, animation, slideshow, slide

I have a script that displays images sort of like a carousel. The images are placed in LIs and the left positioning is changed based on the width of each slide (all the same). Currently, the old slide just disappears then the new one appears.

I would like to make it so they slide in from the side and was wondering if someone could give me a basic example of how to do this using plain JavaScript (no jQuery!).

For example, I'm using the following code to update the left positioning of the containing UL. How can I make it so it will slide the selected image to the left or to the right (depending upon whether the next or previous button is clicked)

```
containingUL.style.left = '-' + (slideNumber * slideWidth) + 'px';
```

Comment: Just curious... why the aversion to JQuery?

Comment: Out of interest, why no jQuery?

Comment: The client is against using it. I know it's totally ridiculous, but there's no way around it. :(

Comment: These two might be of interest: http://dhtmlkitchen.com/ape/example/anim/ and http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib-examples.html#transform. Both are modular and avoid the bloat of jQuery. The latter has been heavily tested in older versions of IE and runs quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a basic element slide function.  You can play with the values of `steps` and `timer` to get the animation speed and smoothness just right.

```
function slideTo(el, left) {
    var steps = 25;
    var timer = 25;
    var elLeft = parseInt(el.style.left) || 0;
    var diff = left - elLeft;
    var stepSize = diff / steps;
    console.log(stepSize, ", ", steps);

    function step() {
        elLeft += stepSize;
        el.style.left = elLeft + "px";
        if (--steps) {
            setTimeout(step, timer);
        }
    }
    step();
}
```

So you could go:

```
slideTo(containingUL, -slideNumber * slideWidth);
```

**Edit:** Forgot to link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EuzAK)

**Edit:** To slide to the left, provide a `left` value less than the current `style.left`.  To slide to the right, provide a value greater than the current `style.left`.  For you it shouldn't matter much.  You should be able to plug it into your existing code.  I'm guessing your current code either increments or decrements `slideNumber` and then sets `style.left` according to the slideNumber.  Something like this should work:

```
if (nextButtonClicked) slideNumber++;
else slideNumber--;
slideTo(containingUL, -slideNumber * slideWidth);
```

I updated the JSFiddle with a working example of a sliding "gallery", including prev and next buttons.  http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/EuzAK/2/

Comment: How can this been updated to create another function for sliding images in from the right? (for going back in the slideshow)

Comment: @Cofey - No need for another function, this will slide either direction depending on the value of the `left` parameter and the current position of the element.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: There's a bug when clicking the button twice (so it runs again before the animation is complete). There are parts of two images showing at once instead of just one. Can you please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @Cofey - You need to store a reference to the value returned by `setTimeout` and make it available in the global scope or at least outside the scope of the click handler.  When the button is clicked, first call `clearTimeout()`.  See this updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/EuzAK/3/.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, non jQuery:

http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/contentslider/slider.html
http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/make_a_javascript_slideshow/
http://javascript.internet.com/miscellaneous/basic-slideshow.html